# ListContourPlot - data display range

Tags: plotting

Defining contours in ListContourPlot seems to work well when the data plotted increases/decreases linearly. Exponential increases (e.g. sharp mountain peak in the center of a slightly changing, surrounding topography) are left white as if data doesn't exist. How can one force the shading to cover this region as well?

Comment: `PlotRange -> All`. Either that, or take the `Log` of your z-values, with the zeros of the function suitably regularized.

Comment: A code sample to reproduce the issue is just about always useful.

Comment: PlotRange seems to only affect the axes in this case and not the bin data. As for taking log of the plot, the values are all ~0.01 - 0.3. The problem is that the features that are mapped out are those in the range of 0.02- 0.06. When above 0.06, it goes blank.

I would show a sample, but it really only happens when I have a very large set of data - a few thousand data points. When sampling subsets of the data, I actually don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too big for a comment:

I'm afraid I can't reproduce your problem. The following code generates a large data set (361,201 coordinates) with a central peak. Using `PlotRange -> All` this peak is imaged just fine. Could you try this example and see if it works for you?

```
f[x_, y_] := Cos[x^2 + y^2] Exp[-((x^2 + y^2))]
step = .01;
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, -3, 3, step}, {y, -3, 3, step}], 1];
ListContourPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Could you tweak the function `f[x,y]` so that it resembles your data, so that we can work with that?